# unknown directive "rtmp" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76

Tags: nginx

I'm trying get up a server to do straming by webcam, I'm a relatively new user from Ubuntu and install Nginx, now, I'm try to modify the nginx.conf and configurate the rtmp server and this is my script file

```
user www-data;

worker_processes 4;

pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {

    worker_connections 768;

    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


rtmp {

    server {

        listen 1935;

        chunk_size 8192;


        application vod {

            play /home/juanbg/vod ;

        }

        application live {

            live on;

            record off;

        }

    }

}
```

To modified this, I used sublime text 3 for ubuntu, I saved the file, and when I try run nginx in the terminal this happen:

```
juanbg@JuanBG:~$ sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "rtmp" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76
```

I read all similiar situations in this website and in others, and all is issue because the rtmp is inside brackets of http (http{rtmp{}}) but in this case not, (or not that I know).

Comment: is rtmp enabled in nginx? e.g. is the rtmp module installed/compiled?

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is quite old but this might be helpfull for others.

When installing nginx for rtmp the program must be compiled from source. ([e.g. as desecribed here](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/))

In short:

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libssl-dev
 wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.2.tar.gz
 wget https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/archive/master.zip
 unzip master.zip     
 tar -zxvf nginx-1.9.2.tar.gz
```

In case you want to use the lastest version from http://nginx.org/download/, then change the version number appropriate.

```
 cd nginx-1.9.2
 ./configure --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module-master
 make
 sudo make install
```

Now the nginx.conf must be changed.

**Make sure to start the right binary, check it with `which nginx` on the command line. This should point to `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx`, otherwise the rtmp-module is unknown.**

start: `nginx`

stop: `nginx -s stop`

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, you just need install the rtmp module.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-rtmp`

`sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: final line should be sudo service (no S) nginx restart

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Docker

Comment: This works, but I also needed to add this line to my config:  `load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;`

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar problem (albeit on another OS):
"nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "rtmp" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/rtmp-enabled/test.conf:2"

```
# uname -ro
FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p1
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-freebsd  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/etc/nginx --with-cc-opt='-I /usr/local/include' --with-ld-opt='-L /usr/local/lib' --conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --user=www --group=www --modules-path=/usr/local/libexec/nginx --with-file-aio --with-threads --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_smtp_module --with-mail_ssl_module --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/client_body_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-pcre --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --add-dynamic-module=/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/nginx-rtmp-module-1.2.1
```

It's work for me:

After make (make install clean), edit config (/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) and add line:

```
load_module /usr/local/libexec/nginx/ngx_rtmp_module.so;
```

For Linux, the path to the library will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Hey try to link the modules-available to modules-enabled

```
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-rtmp.conf /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-rtmp.conf
```

Worked for me.

Also check the link where I found the solution.

https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/uo0nd5/comment/i8bkspi/

Answer (score 0):

Install nginx via homebrew follwing http://brew.sh/homebrew-nginx/. Make sure to use the `--with-rtmp-module` flag.

Also note that this installs to `/usr/local/etc/nginx`